# Selecting child of previous parent jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lately I've been trying my hand at animation using CSS and jQuery, it went well, however, now I want to do a bit more.
  That is, once the user clicks information should show up on top of the image.

At the moment, I just have a few  tags on which I perform the animations and class toggles.

My question is, I've thought about doing the following:

```
<div class= "singleImage">
    <img src.... class="actualImage">
    <p>text to put over the image</p>
</div>
```

This would be done per image which means that I'll have about 5 of them with different images.

However, I don't know how to go about selecting the previous element of class "actualImage".

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Check out jQuery's [Tree Traversal API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function. Example: Assume you want to select the image previous to the second image:

```
var foo = $(".singleImage").eq(1);
var bar = $(foo).prev().find('.actualImage');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFLXg/)

Comment: I tried it with the following syntax : $(this).prev(".actualImage"); but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('singleImage').children('.actualImage').prev();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are trying to select the previous element, but you could do something akin to this:

- Bind a function to the click event for the element containing your image and caption.

  - Inside this function, toggle the caption.
  - Also, bind a click event handler to the body to detect clicks "off" the containing element.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="has-caption">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <span class="caption">This is a caption</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.has-caption { position: relative; }
a.has-caption .caption {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
a.has-caption img { vertical-align: bottom }
```

JavaScript

```
$('a.has-caption').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
    var self  = $(this)
      , tmpId = 'toggle-' + Date.now();
    self.addClass(tmpId);
    $('span.caption', self).toggle();
    $('body').one('click', function(e) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest('.' + tmpId).length) {
            $('span.caption', '.' + tmpId).hide();
            self.removeClass(tmpId);
        };
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/83s7W/